# PHP PDO SESSION not able to redirect

Tags: javascript, php, session, pdo

I am using session through login form , but when trying to login its not redirecting to index.php . please let me know where i am mistaken.
below is my code for index and login

```
         <?php 
         session_start();

           if (!isset($_SESSION['user_name'])) {
            header("location: login.php");
             }
             else{
              echo "welcome $user_name";
             ?>
```

following with html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Admin Panel</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="admin_style.css">
</head>
<body>

<h1>Welcome To Home Page</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

```
           <?php } ?>
```

below login.php code with form

```
            <?php
             session_start();
            ?>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Admin Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="login.php" action="post">
 <table width="400" align="center" border="20">

 <tr>
  <td colspan="5" align="center" bgcolor="gray"><h1>Admin Login</h1></td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
  <td align="right">User Name:</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="user_name"></td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
  <td align="right">User Password</td>
  <td><input type="password" name="user_pass"></td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
  <td align="center" colspan="5"><input type="submit" name="login" value="Login"></td>
  
 </tr>
  
 </table>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

```
    <?php 
include("connect.php");

if(isset($_POST['login'])) {

    $user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
    $user_pass = $_POST['user_pass'];

    $sth = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM admin_login WHERE user_name='$user_name' AND user_password='$user_pass'");


     $sth->execute();


    if($sth->rowCount() > 0) {

        $_SESSION['user_name'] = $user_name;
        header("Location: index.php"); // Redirecting To index Page
        } else {
       echo "<script>alert('Username or Password is invalid')</script>";
       }  

}


?>
```

through this code i am just able to see on address bar line and no javascript alert:
http://localhost/malala/admin/login.php?user_name=kitchen&user_pass=kitchen&login=Login

Please help ....

Comment: Do not ever send or store clear password! Even more with `GET` methods, this is really really dangerous

Answer (score 0):

`http://localhost/malala/admin/login.php?user_name=kitchen&user_pass=kitchen&login=Login` Send the variable as `GET` and you're looking for them as `POST`

Comment: Thank you Alok Patel its working now but what about javascript error its not poping up